# Using Pointers for ios App & Javascript website

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, pointers, parse-platform

I have an iphone app created as a multiplication game and saves the following into a class called 'Results'.

`PFObject *Results = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Result"];
    [Results setObject:levelNumberLabel.text forKey:@"LevelNumber"];
    [Results saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) etc.`

I also have a class called 'currentUser' that stores the following:

`PFObject *currentUser = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"currentUser"];
    [currentUser setObject:_firstnameLabel.text forKey:@"SFirstName"];`

I want to run a javascript query that 'links' these two tables. I have a point
er set up called 'currentuser' in the currentUser class and a pointer called 'currentResult'.. These hold no value (undefined).

How am I able to merge these classes together? Will it be a case of linking it through the app or using javascript? I'm slightly confused. Here is my javascript code

```
 var Show = Parse.Object.extend("Result");
var query = new Parse.Query(Show);
query.include('currentUser');
query.find({
  success: function(shows) {
    for(var i = 0; i < shows.length; i++) {
        var show = results[i];
        var surname = results.get('SSurname');
        console.log(i);
        var users = show.get('currentUser');
        var username = users.get("SFirstName");
        $(".success").append(username + " on " + surname + "<br/>");
```

Any questions/help please let me know.

Any help on the subject would be greatly appreciated

Comment: A user plays the game and generates a result?  You'd like to find all results generated by a particular user?  I think that's the question.  The Result table should have a column of pointer type, pointing to the User table.  That column must be initialized when you save a Result.  To query, the query must be qualified with .equalTo() to find a given user's results.  The question and code contain some unconventional wording choices, making it a little bit tough to understand.

Comment: Hi Danh.. Thanks for that!

So Will I have to change my PFObject to a PFQuery? I'm still pretty unsure of the iOS side of things, would a sample code be too much to ask for? I do apologise but I'm new to Parse. I can do the javascript querying now but initializing the pointer is pretty new to me. Thanks

Comment: Did my best... a little design advice, a little naming advice and a little coding advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse already gives us a User class (PFUser).  Consider starting with that one.

Next, create a class that represents the result of play. "Result" (singular) is an okay name for that.  It can have string and number attributes as you see fit. (name those starting with lower case, e.g. "levelNumber").  To associate a result with a user, the Result table must also have a pointer attribute to the User, call it "user".

In Objective-C, when its time to save the result of play:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser]; // this is the signed in PFUser
PFObject *result = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Result"];
result[@"user"] = user;
result[@"some_other_col_name"] = some_other_value;
[result saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

In JS, to find the all of the results created by the play of some user:

```
// if this is called in a cloud function, the request.user will be
// the PFUser on the client that made the request
function resultsForUser(user) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Result");
    query.equalTo("user" user);
    return query.find().then(function(results) {
        // results are the Result objects whose user is the given user
    }, function (error) {

    });
}
```